Verification Error: "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.."
I created an app for Android and iOS and I'm using firebase services for authentication.
While most of the devices don't have issues, I still have few Android users who are getting the following error message when trying to log in-
"This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]"
When I have tried to reproduce this on my Android/iOS devices I didn't get any issues..
*All users have downloaded the app from the stores. When I have tried to reproduce the issues I have also used the app from the stores.
The user has entered the phone number and hit the continue button to get the OTP code. Right after doing so, the error message popped up.
According to the correct flow, after the user hit the continue button, an OTP code should be sent to the device and the user can paste it and enter the app.
